# What does the 'f' mean in OpenGL functions (like glRotatef)?

Tags: opengl

Practically every function in OpenGL (or PyOpenGL at the very least) have an `f` at the end, like `glRotatef` and `glColor3f` etc., but I can't find out what it means. Does it work like `1.0f` where it uses single-precision float numbers by default?

While I'm here (if I'm allowed to ask 2 questions), what's the difference between `glColor3f` and `glColor3fv`?

Comment: Did you look at [glColor](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)?

Comment: I hadn't; I didn't know it could come without a suffix so I didn't look in that way. Thanks for the pointer! Turns out my guess was right haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `f` tells that the function is expecting a `float`. So if there was an `i` that tells the function would be expecting an `int`. The `v` represents a vector so `glColor3fv` expects a "float vector" in other words an array of floats.

This is clearly reflected in the documentation for [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

```
void glColor3f(GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue);
void glColor3fv(const GLfloat *v);
```

The format is more explicitly explained in the specification:

> A final `v` character, if present, indicates that the command takes a pointer to an array (a vector) of values rather than a series of individual arguments.
>
> In general, a command declaration has the form
>
> ```
> rtype Name{∈1234}{∈ b s i i64 f d ub us ui ui64}{∈v}
> ```
>
> `rtype` is the return type of the function. The braces ({}) enclose a series of type descriptors (see the table bellow), of which one is selected. ∈ indicates no type descriptor.
>
> If there are no letters, then the arguments’ type is given explicitly. If the final character is not `v`, then `N` is given by the digit 1, 2, 3, or 4 (if there is no digit, then the number of arguments is fixed).
>
> If the final character is `v`, then only `arg1` is present and it is an array of `N` values of the indicated type.
>
> ```
> +------+----------------------------------+
> | Type | Descriptor Corresponding GL Type |
> +------+----------------------------------+
> | b    | byte                             |
> | s    | short                            |
> | i    | int                              |
> | i64  | int64                            |
> | f    | float                            |
> | d    | double                           |
> | ub   | ubyte                            |
> | us   | ushort                           |
> | ui   | uint                             |
> | ui64 | uint64                           |
> +------+----------------------------------+
> ```
>
> – *[OpenGL 4.5 Specification, Page 11 and 12](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf)*

*The ∈ symbol means "is an element of".*

The same principle is used for various things, say `GL_RGBA32F` vs `GL_RGBA8I`. This isn't specific to OpenGL, various libraries uses a prefix of the type it expects or returns.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for, and that linked page is super useful

Comment: @polarisfox64: if you're wondering about *why* all of this is necessary, OpenGL is a C API, and C does not have function overloads...